# Can I flash update.zip of titanium backup to non-rooted device

Tags: root-access, titanium-backup

I was searching for an answer but I couldn't find any explanation if I'm able to flash update.zip of Titanium backup to non-rooted device.

Comment: Only if that unrooted device has an open/custom recovery, like [tag:twrp].

Comment: I adb sideloaded update..zip through twrp and I got bootloop, then sideloaded Magisk and sideloaded update.zip again and it fixed. So, don't you think it has to be rooted or this is the problem of my phone?

Comment: make sure the issue is not related to secure boot https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/dm-verity

Comment: TWRP has root access. And to what @alecxs wrote: that would explain why flashing Magisk solved it (Magisk does deal with dm-verity, as I know first-hand from one of my devices).